# What has replaced QGIS SPIT (Shapefile to PostGIS Import Tool)?

Tags: postgis, qgis-plugins

On page 132 of [PostGIS in Action, Second Edition](https://www.manning.com/books/postgis-in-action-second-edition) it says,

> **QGIS SPIT** QGIS comes packaged with a tool called SPIT that allows you to batch-load Esri shapefiles into a PostgreSQL database, bypassing rendering. One crippling annoyance with this tool is its automatic conversion of all field names to uppercase. In PostgreSQL, uppercase field names must be double-quoted in queries, and that’s a lot of extra typing of quotes. If you’re going to use SPIT, we suggest that you create a function to convert everything back to lowercase after import.

I found it [documented here](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_spit.html). However it seems that the tool according to [this discussion was removed](https://www.mail-archive.com/qgis-developer@lists.osgeo.org/msg30019.html). And this [bug report](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/issues/806) shows it was purged and is no longer distributed with QGIS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the QGIS plugin **DbManager** instead.  DbManager has similiar capability to import shape files and other goodies that SPIT never had and also doesn't have the issues we noted in the book about SPIT. That's also covered in 5.3 QGIS section, though I guess we focused on the query capability of it rather than the import capability.  The import is the down arrow icon next to the wrench icon.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `DB Manager` in the `Database` menu. Then you will find a button called `Import layer/file` to import a new layer into your database.
[image]

You can also use the `Processing toolbox` and then there is a button in `QGIS geoalgorithms` -> `Database` -> `Import into PostGIS`
[image]